# Regular expression to check a string with 4 digits and the space?

Tags: c#, regex, string

Need a regular expression to check a string with 4 digit and the space in trail.

I have tried

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(ln.TrimStart(), @"^[0-9]{4}.*"))
```

and also

```
Regex.IsMatch(line.TrimStart(), @"^\d{4}")
```

Valid are

```
0990 09253U108      BX    
0990 02376R102      AAL
```

But don't know why it is also consedring as valid

```
00000003610014112202013               2                5
00000003610014112192013               2               47
```

I don't want above 2 lines. How can I fix my regular expression?
In continuation,
Can you help me how to check the below string line

```
 C              DTCCUS33XXX    2039   92857W209      VOD    USD  VOD    C 04/19/2014   39.000  04/19/2014                     200
```

Is it possible to validate the 2039 for its position using regular expression..

currently i am doing

```
line.Substring(31, 7).Trim().ToString();
```

but want it to be done using regular expression..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to start with 4 digits and a space, use `\s` to match space. Currently you don't have it and it matches anything starting with 4 digits.

```
@"^[0-9]{4}\s.*"
```

Answer (score 1):

`^[0-9]{4}\s.*` enforces the space

Answer (score 0):

```
^[0-9]{4}.*
         ^^ matches anything
```

You want `@"^[0-9]{4}\s.*"`